# keystoneJS does not use correct linked css file

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, pug, keystonejs

I linked an own css file in my new keystonejs project. Its in /styles/themes/index.css (also tried without the themes folder). The file is correct linked in my jade file. I checked the rendered code in my browsers and was able to open the linked stlye.css with all styles in it.

But keystone does not load these styles from index.css.

index.jade

```
extends ../layouts/default
block css 
    link(href="/styles/themes/index.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css")
block content
    .container
        .row
            .col-xs-3.col-sm-2.col-md-2#navigation-stuff
                p Sidebar text
            .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-10#article-stuff
                p article container text
```

rendered result in browser:

```
<link href="/styles/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/styles/index.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css">
```

And no, I have no typing errors. The IDs in the less file are exactly the same as in the jade code.

Comment: Please update your question and delete your comment so it's obvious without read comments. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your index.css? Might make it helpful to diagnose what's wrong

Comment: np, heres the less code. But I dont think it has mistakes because keystone wouldnt compile it to css (and this test styles are very small).
`#navigation-stuff {
 background-color: lightblue;
 height: 500px;
}
#article-stuff {
 background-color: deeppink;
 height: 700px;
}
#footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: yellowgreen;
}
p {
 font-size: 40px !important;
}`

Comment: ok, found the soluction. I blamed myself. I had a typing error. I wrote rel="stylesheet**s**" instead of stylesheet.

Comment: You may facepalm now.